# How to get rid of specific quests in Fallout 4?

Tags: fallout-4

So, the quest `Taking out the Trash` appears to be buggy. The quest looks like this:

[image: quest progress]

However, I can't turn it in anymore, and I can't even "unfollow" it so the marker is not displayed anymore. Furthermore, the marker is located at outpost Zimonja, which doesn't make ANY sense at all.

Since this is annoying as hell, I want to get rid of the quest, but this proofs more difficult than I thought. According to [the fallout wikia](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Taking_Out_the_Trash), the Quest has the Editor_ID `DLC04_RQ_KillTroubleMaker`. But when I run `sqt` in the console, there is no such quest. I only have:

```
MS05MiscSalem
DLC04MQ06a_HCSynthQuest
DLCMQ04RewardMisc
DLC04RaiderKickout
FFDiamondCity07FIN
FFDiamondCity06
SLC04MS01
FFDiamondCity08
BoSFFMaster
DLC04ShankMiscObjective
DLC04ParkPopulationHandler
DLC04_RQ_StealCache
DLC04MS02
DLC04KyeDialogue
```

None of these quests is `Taking out the Trash`, i checked all of them. So I have no idea how to get rid of this specific quest. Any tips or advices?

Comment: Your username checks out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this specific quest at all, but did you try using the console to set the stage of the quest to the last stage you successfully completed?  Or what if you just restart the quest entirely? Of course make sure you save before messing with your quests through the console, it can really mess up a save if something goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your console commands have no solid solution I would recommend a mod that allows you to remove quests from your data center. (similar to Skyrim's quest remover, which allowed one to remove quests from the journal, via going to the cistern and paying the bartender a small fee to remove the quest from the journal)

Fallout 4 has a similar mod for PC located here: https://www.nexusmods.com/fallout4/mods/7396/

Fallout 4 has a mod for the Xbox One here: https://bethesda.net/en/mods/fallout4/mod-detail/2196820

At this time, PS4 does not have a mod available for this caliber, due to SONY restrictions.